# Python: smarter way to calculate loan payments

Tags: python, algorithm, math, finance

How to calculate the monthly fee on a loan?

Given is:

- a: an amount to loan.
- b: the loan period (number of months).
- c: the interest rate p.a. (interests is calculated and added every month, 1/12 of the interest is added. So if the interest is on 12%, 1% interest is added every month).
- d: the amount of money owed after the end of the period.

This problem is a bit different than the usual since, the goal is not to have the loan payed after the loan period has ended, but to still owe an amount that is given. I have been able to find an algorithm so solve the problem if I wanted to pay the entire amount, but it will of course not work for this problem where the goal is to end up owing a given amount rather than not owing anything.

I managed to make a solution to this problem by starting with an guess and then keep on improving that guess until it was close enough. I wondered however, if there is a better way to simply calculate this, rather than just guessing.

**Edit: Here's how I'm doing it now.**

```
def find_payment(start, end, months, interest):
    difference = start
    guess = int(start / months * interest)
    while True:
        total = start
        for month in range(1, months + 1):
            ascribe = total * interest / 12
            total = total + ascribe - guess
        difference = total - end
        # See if the guess was good enough.
        if abs(difference) > start * 0.001:
            if difference < 0:
                if abs(difference) < guess:
                    print "payment is %s" % guess
                    return evolution(start, guess, interest, months)
                else:
                    mod = int(abs(difference) / start * guess)
                    if mod == 0:
                        mod = 1
                    guess -= mod
            else:
                mod = int(difference / start * guess)
                if mod == 0:
                    mod = 1
                guess += mod
        else:
            print "payment is %s" % guess
            return evolution(start, guess, interest, months)
```

evolution is just a function that displays how the loan would look like payment for payment and interest for interest, summing up total amount of interest paid etc.

An example would be if I wanted to find out the monthly payments for a loan starting with $100k and ending at $50k with an interest of 8% and a duration of 70 months, calling

```
>>> find_payment(100000, 50000, 70, 0.08)
payment is 1363
```

In the above case I would end up owing 49935, and I went through the loop 5 times. The amount of times needed to go through the loop depends on how close I want to get to the amount and it varies a bit.

Comment: maybe if you can provide your guessing solution, it becomes clearer on what you want to do.

Comment: isn't this just a simple geometric progression?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: What is the function "evolution()" doing? Where can I find that function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a basically a [mortgage repayment calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator).

Assuming that start is greater than end, and that interest is between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0.1 for 10% interest)

First consider the part of the payment you want to pay off.

```
Principal = start - end
```

The monthly payment is given by:

```
pay_a = (interest / 12) / (1 - (1+interest/12) ^ (-months))) * Principal
```

You then need to consider the extra interest. Which is just equal to the remaining principal times the monthly interest

```
pay_b = interest / 12 * end
```

So the total payment is

```
payment = (interest / 12) * (1 / (1 - (1+interest/12) ^ (-months))) * Principal + end)
```

On the example you gave of

```
Start: 100000
End:  50000
Months: 70
Interest: 8% 
pay_a = 896.20
pay_b = 333.33
Payment = 1229.54
```

When I tested these values in Excel, after 70 payments the remaing loan was 50,000. This is assuming you pay the interest on the notional before the payment is made each month.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the easiest way to think about this is to split the loan in two parts, one part which is to be repaid in full and another part where you don't pay off anything. You have already computed the monthly fee for the first part.

Comment: +1, exactly! Simplest accounting equivalence in the books, really.

Comment: Clever to split the loan into two parts, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep paying the interest of every month; then, you will alway owe the same amont.

```
Owe_1 = a

Int_2 = Owe_1*(InterestRate/12)
Pay_2 = Int_2
Owe_2 = Owe_1 + Int_2 - Pay_2 # ==> Owe_1 + Int_2 - Int_2 = Owe_1

Int_3 = Owe_2*(InterestRate/12)
Pay_3 = Int_3
Owe_3 = Owe_2 + Int_3 - Pay_3 # ==> Owe_2 + Int_3 - Int_3 = Owe_2 = Owe_1
```

Answer (score 0):

**python code to calculate emi**

```
class EMI_CALCULATOR(object):
 # Data attributes
 # Helps to calculate EMI

  Loan_amount = None # assigning none values
  Month_Payment = None # assigning none values
  Interest_rate = None #assigning none values
  Payment_period = None #assigning none values

  def get_loan_amount(self):
 #get the  value of loan amount
      self.Loan_amount = input("Enter The Loan amount(in rupees) :")
      pass

  def get_interest_rate(self):
   # get the value of interest rate
      self.Interest_rate = input("Enter The Interest rate(in percentage(%)) : ")
      pass

  def get_payment_period(self):
   # get the payment period"
      self.Payment_period = input("Enter The Payment period (in month): ")
      pass


  def calc_interest_rate(self):
  # To calculate the  interest rate"
      self.get_interest_rate()

      if self.Interest_rate > 1:
         self.Interest_rate = (self.Interest_rate /100.0) 

      else:
         print "You have not entered The interest rate correctly ,please try again "
      pass

  def calc_emi(self):
  # To calculate the EMI"          

      try:

        self.get_loan_amount() #input loan amount 
        self.get_payment_period() #input payment period
        self.calc_interest_rate() #input interest rate and calculate the interest rate

      except NameError:
             print "You have not entered Loan amount (OR) payment period (OR) interest rate  correctly,Please enter and try again. "

      try:
        self.Month_Payment = (self.Loan_amount*pow((self.Interest_rate/12)+1,
                             (self.Payment_period))*self.Interest_rate/12)/(pow(self.Interest_rate/12+1,
                             (self.Payment_period)) - 1)

      except ZeroDivisionError: 
                    print "ERROR!! ZERO DIVISION ERROR , Please enter The Interest rate correctly and Try again."

      else:
         print "Monthly Payment is : %r"%self.Month_Payment
      pass


  if __name__ == '__main__':# main method 

        Init = EMI_CALCULATOR() # creating  instances


        Init.calc_emi() #to calculate EMI
```

for more info visit : https://emilgeorgejames.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/python-emi-equated-monthly-installment-calculator/

Answer (score 0):

This rather a detailed way but will give the whole payment as well

```
# Mortgage Loan that gives the balance and total payment per year

# Function that gives the monthly payment
def f1 (principle,annual_interest_rate,duration):
    r = annual_interest_rate/1200
    n = duration*12
    a=principle*r*((1+r)**n)
    b= (((1+r)**n)- 1)
    if r > 0 :
        MonthlyPayment = (a/b)
    else :
        MonthlyPayment = principle/n

    return MonthlyPayment

# Function that gives the balance
def f2 (principle,annual_interest_rate,duration,number_of_payments):
    r = annual_interest_rate/1200
    n = duration*12
    a= ((1+r)**n)
    b= ((1+r)**number_of_payments)
    c= (((1+r)**n)-1)
    if r > 0 :
        RemainingLoanBalance = principle*((a-b)/c)
    else :
        RemainingLoanBalance = principle*(1-(number_of_payments/n))

    return RemainingLoanBalance
# Entering the required values
principle=float(input("Enter loan amount: "))
annual_interest_rate=float(input("Enter annual interest rate (percent): "))
duration=int(input("Enter loan duration in years: "))

# Output that returns all useful data needed
print ("LOAN AMOUNT:",principle,"INTEREST RATE (PERCENT):",annual_interest_rate)
print ("DURATION (YEARS):",duration,"MONTHLY PAYMENT:",int(f1(principle,annual_interest_rate,duration)))


k=duration+1
BALANCE=principle
total=0
for i in range (1,k):
    TOTALPAYMENT= f1(BALANCE,annual_interest_rate,k-i)*12
    total+= TOTALPAYMENT
    BALANCE= f2(principle,annual_interest_rate,duration,12*i)
    print("YEAR:",i,"BALANCE:",int(BALANCE),"TOTAL PAYMENT",int(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def EMI_calc(principle, rate, time, frequency):
    return (principle / ((1-((1+(rate/frequency))**(-1*(time*frequency))))/(rate/frequency)))

print("""
----- Welcome to EMI programe for Python -----
""")
print("\n You have chosen to know the EMI for Loan.\n")
input('\nTo Continue Press ENTER --- to ABORT Press ctrl+c > \n')

print("\nPlease Enter amount of Loan to be taken: >\n")
principle = int(input())
print("\nEnter rate of interst (%): >\n")
rate = float(input())/100
print("\nEnter Term (Years): >\n")
time = float(input())
print("\nPlease enter the frequency of installments) : >\n")
frequency = int(input())

EMI = round(EMI_calc(principle, rate, time, frequency),0)

print("""

---------------------------------------------------------------------

""")
print(f"""
The EMI for Loan of Rs.{principle};
at interest rate of {rate*100} % for {time} years;
would be: Rs.""", EMI)

print("""

---------------------------------------------------------------------

""")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet using numpy functions. This shows you the payment, principal, interest, instalment and total_amount each month. Run it and see the output. You can also check the syntax for Excel "IPMT()" and "PPMT()" functions for more explanation of the arguments.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.pmt.html#numpy.pmt

```
import math
import numpy as np
rate = 0.08
start_amount = 100000.0
end_amount = 50000.0
diff_amount = start_amount - end_amount
# nr_years = 4
payment_frequency = int (12)
nr_months = 70 # = nr_years * payment_frequency
per_np = np.arange (nr_months) + 1 # +1 because index starts with 1 here
pay_b = rate / payment_frequency * end_amount
ipmt_np = np.ipmt (rate / payment_frequency, per_np, nr_months, diff_amount) - pay_b
ppmt_np = np.ppmt (rate / payment_frequency, per_np, nr_months, diff_amount)
for payment in per_np:
    idx = payment - 1
    principal = math.fabs (ppmt_np [idx])
    start_amount = start_amount - principal
    interest = math.fabs (ipmt_np [idx])
    instalment = principal + interest
    print payment, "\t", principal, "\t", interest, "\t\t", instalment, "\t\t", start_amount
print np.sum (ipmt_np)
```